# Visual Studio 2012 Database Deployments with variable substitution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, database-project

I'm in the process of setting up deployments in visual studio for several related databases for the first time.  Currently I have three databases that I'll call Database1, Database2, and Database3.  These databases have multiple levels of deployment (development, test, staging, and production).

So for Database1 I have 4 publish configurations:

```
  Database1_ToDevelopment.publish.xml
  Database1_ToTest.publish.xml
  Database1_ToStaging.publish.xml
  Database1_ToProduction.publish.xml
```

Production is housed on it's own server, and the database is actually called "Database1_production".  Test and Staging share a server and the databases are called "Database1_test" and "Database1_staging".   Development is on it's own server, and called "Database1_development".

My problem is this: synonyms.

[This answer is almost useful, but not quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642874/visual-studio-2010-database-project-unresolved-reference-to-a-synonym)

Database1_development may contain this:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[syn_mytable] FOR [Database2_development].[dbo].[mytable]
```

I can't take that synonym and move it from development to test.  I need to substitute the "_development" part for "_test".  And that's based on the deployment.

I guess what I want to know is how to get a variable substitution based on the deployment.

---

Of course, then I partially answered my own question.  I found this image on which is exactly what I wanted but *no explanation* of why this dialog has this section (no explanation, so no link).  The dialog looks familiar but that SQLCMD variable part isn't there in VS 2012.

[image]

Turns out, this portion of the dialog won't show unless you edit the XML file for the publish profile to add something like this:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <SqlCmdVariable Include="DBLevel">
           <Value>Dev</Value>
        </SqlCmdVariable>
    </ItemGroup>
```

I found this through [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346977/how-to-use-msbuild-properties-in-sqlproj-sql-server-2012-script) question, and then Jamie Thomson's [blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/12/10/editing-sqlcmdvariable-nodes-in-ssdt-publish-profile-files-using-msbuild.aspx).

It magically appears when the next time the publish dialog is opened again.

Then in the synonym definition I can just say:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[syn_mytable] FOR [Database2_$(DBLevel)].[dbo].[mytable]
```

Which is what I wanted, mostly.

Comment: Pretty sure you define the variables in the Project properties. You then put the values in your publish profiles. We've used these for things like Linked Servers and different file paths hard-coded in some of our legacy stored procs. This was what I would have suggested as the solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

A **workaround solution** would be to use ExecuteSQL or ExecuteDDL task from [MsBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) lib or any other task library to create environment - specific aliases as a part of your build process (e.g. post-build events). This way you can store db names as MSBuild properties.

Comment: To be honest, we're trying desperately to get *away* from non-standard toolkits for our builds and deployments.  Thank you for the suggestion though.